# how to set title/add action bar in android apps when using setListAdapter

Tags: android, android-listview

I created a List using setListAdapter.However i am not able to see the title or able to set title or action bar.My code is below.Any help will be appreciated

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    String[] values = new String[] { "Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile",
             "Max OS X"};
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}
```

}

Comment: You might add a Header... but this one will vanish when you scroll the ListView. Better think to something static **outside** the ListView.

Comment: how do i add header ?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addHeaderView(android.view.View, java.lang.Object, boolean)

Comment: thanks i m now able to add headers but say if i want to add something like menu (something like action bar ) then what should i do because in creating header only some text can be added.

Comment: `only some text can be added.` **False**. You can add a **full layout**. If you want to use an ActionBar, then you have to follow a **different path** (please Google on how to - the **developer.com** site is your reference).